# How to hit Microsoft language detection API through POSTMAN

Tags: azure, postman, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-api

I am running Language Detection Cognitive Service API locally(by using below command).

docker run --rm -it -p 5003:5003 --memory 1g --cpus 1 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/speechservices/language-detection Eula=accept Billing=https://****.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken ApiKey=******* HTTP_PROXY=********

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MFeT.png)

Issue: Getting 404 when i am hitting through Postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHsbu.png)

Note: My cognitive service region is westeurope and Pricing tier F0

Please let me know right way to test locally running congnitive api

Answer (score 0):

@SanK, are you trying to do Speech Language Detection or TextAnalytics Language Detection?  Because that is two different features, make sure your subscription register with the correct one.

Speech Language Detection - Detect the language from Speech.
TextAnalytics Language Detection - Detect the language from Text.

Comment: Thanks for clearning my doubt. i understand the above screenshots provided by you are for TextAnalytics , that i have already set it up and working. I am sill looking how to test Speech Language Detection - Detect the language from Speech.  you can see my 1st image where i am able to run the  Speech Language Detection but now sure how to test it

Answer (score 0):

### Local Run

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5003:5003 --memory 1g --cpus 1 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/speechservices/language-detection Eula=accept Billing=https://.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken ApiKey=*** HTTP_PROXY=********
```

In your case, your `Billing` value is incorrect: you have set `https://.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken` but you should use your Endpoint URI which is visible on your Azure resource Overview page, see below for my resource:
[image: Cognitive Resource Overview]

This is well described in the official documentation (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-container-howto?tabs=lid%2Ccsharp%2Csimple-format&WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#run-the-container-with-docker-run))

### Consumption

Then, with your postman, you should call your local instance. In your capture, you are calling the API on Microsoft side (https://westeurope...). You should use http://localhost:5003/speech/languagedetection/cognitiveservices/v1 as visible in the swagger capture you posted